# Swift Fortune Wheel changing color issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, github, cocoapods

Im making an app where i have to add fortune wheel, for this i search the pod and find this library very useful https://github.com/sh-khashimov/SwiftFortuneWheel. Almost every thing is customisable but now i'm facing one issue with the library. i have a requirement that each slice color will be change once wheel stop, means winning color will be different and losing color will be different after wheel stop. i try to update it color is changing but now wheel is not stoping at correct index. which was stoping before i update color. can any one let me know what i'm doing wrong here. im pasting my code implentation here too. also i raised detail issue in github too https://github.com/sh-khashimov/SwiftFortuneWheel/issues/20.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftFortuneWheel

class VariousWheelPodiumViewController: UIViewController {

var selectedIndex = -1


@IBOutlet weak var wheelControl: SwiftFortuneWheel!

var prizes = [(id:0,name: "MONEYMONEY", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1),losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1), textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)),
              (id:1,name: "GRAPHIC", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.9098039216, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1), losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
              (id:2,name: "HOME", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1),losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1), textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)),
              (id:3,name: "IDEA", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.9098039216, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1), winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1), losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)),
              (id:4,name: "MANAGMENT", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1), losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
              (id:5,name: "SEARCH", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.9098039216, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1),  losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
              (id:6,name: "TARGET", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.768627451, blue: 0.568627451, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1),  losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)),
              (id:7,name: "TIME", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.9098039216, blue: 0.8274509804, alpha: 1),winningColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9333333333, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.2705882353, alpha: 1), losingColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.737254902, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.6156862745, alpha: 1),textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]



var slices = [Slice] ()

var finishIndex: Int {
    return Int.random(in: 0..<wheelControl.slices.count)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    wheelControl.configuration = .variousWheelPodiumConfiguration
    wheelControl.spinImage = "center"
    wheelControl.isSpinEnabled = false
    updateSlice()
    wheelControl.slices = slices
    
    
}

@IBAction func rotateTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let finishingIndex = self.finishIndex
    print(finishingIndex)
    wheelControl.startRotationAnimation(finishIndex: finishingIndex, continuousRotationTime: 1) { (isFinished) in
        guard isFinished else { return }
        print(self.prizes[finishingIndex])
        self.selectedIndex = finishingIndex
        self.updateSlice()
        self.wheelControl.slices = self.slices
        self.wheelControl.rotate(toIndex: finishingIndex)
    }
}

func updateSlice(){
    slices = []
    for (index,prize) in prizes.enumerated() {
        print(index,prize.name)
        
        var titleTextPreferences = TextPreferences(textColorType: .customPatternColors(colors: nil, defaultColor: .black), font: .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .bold), verticalOffset: 20)
            titleTextPreferences.horizontalOffset = 10
            titleTextPreferences.orientation = .vertical
            titleTextPreferences.spacing = 0
            titleTextPreferences.alignment = .left
            
        var descriptionTextPreferences = TextPreferences(textColorType: .customPatternColors(colors: nil, defaultColor: .red), font: .systemFont(ofSize: 10), verticalOffset:-75)

        descriptionTextPreferences.horizontalOffset = 0
        descriptionTextPreferences.orientation = .vertical
        descriptionTextPreferences.spacing = 0
        descriptionTextPreferences.alignment = .left

        let content: [Slice.ContentType] = [.text(text: prize.name, preferences: titleTextPreferences),.text(text: prize.name, preferences: descriptionTextPreferences)]

        var slice = Slice(contents: content)
        if selectedIndex == -1{
            slice.backgroundColor = prize.color
        }else{
            slice.backgroundColor = index == selectedIndex ? prize.winningColor : prize.losingColor
        }
        slices.append(slice)
    }
   
}
}
```

Comment: Because you are calling updateSlice() in the rotateTap guy?

Comment: yes i need to do it once rotation end i need to update slice color. because wining color is different than the color of slice which was at the start before rotation

Comment: There are a few issues here, but a little clarification... are you trying to pick **2** random numbers? Spin to the 1st and set the slice background color depending on if the two random numbers match? That is, you get `3` as the 1st random number... spin so it stops at slice id 3 ("IDEA"), then get `4` as the 2nd random number and set "IDEA" slice background color to `losingColor`, but if `3` is *also* the 2nd random number, set "IDEA" slice background color to `winnngColor`?

Comment: no, i m just picking one random number since its computed property so im using my local variable there "selectedIndex". so once i get this i just go to update slice method and check array index which matches with that selectedindex which basically the same as "finishingIndex", once it match i put winning color on its background and losing color to other. initially i set selectedIndex -1 to get different background than winning or losing, as initially color background is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could loop through the **current** slices and set their background colors directly. Quick testing of that code, though, and it doesn't work. Apparently, anytime you touch a "slice" object, the wheel resets its rotation.

You can try replacing your `rotateTap(...)` function with this:

```
@IBAction func rotateTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let finishingIndex = self.finishIndex
    print(finishingIndex)
    wheelControl.startRotationAnimation(finishIndex: finishingIndex, continuousRotationTime: 1) { (isFinished) in
        guard isFinished else { return }
        print(self.prizes[finishingIndex])
        self.selectedIndex = finishingIndex
        self.updateSlice()
        self.wheelControl.slices = self.slices
        
        // set rotation async on main queue 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.wheelControl.rotate(toIndex: finishingIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

See if that gives you acceptable results. If not, there is a more complex work-around, but ideally modify the `SwiftFortuneWheel` code to provide for a "modify slice property" solution.